# can i get smooth transition between straight line and curve in SVG?

Tags: svg

so in svg if i do

```
<path d="M30 100 Q 80 30, 100 100 T 200 80" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
```

it smooths the existing bezier curve end point to produce another bezier curve with end point specified after `T`

so in this case curve before `T` has to be a bezier curve, can i achieve the effect in case where first curve is a straight line.

I know I can do it with cubic bezier and quadratic bezier with too.

Just wanted to know if there is some shortcut for this case where **I want a bezier curve to start smoothly from a line** or as an extension from any kind of path

Comment: [No.](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataCurveCommands) For the `S/s` command: "If there is no previous command or if the previous command was not an C, c, S or s, assume the first control point is coincident with the current point.", The equivalent is said for the `T/t` command. Grafical editors offer those kind of restrictions in their UI.

Comment: @ccprog that was really helpful, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You cah draw a line using the path command like this:

```html
<path d="M10,10 L90,90" />
```

You can also use a quadratic Bézier to draw the same line. The idea is to get the coordinates of a point on that line: in this case I'm using x:50, y:50.

```html
 <path d="M10,10 Q50,50 90,90" />
```

Now you can use the T command:

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 250 150">
  <path d="M10,10 Q50,50 90,90T200,80" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is specifically about smoothly connecting a Bézier Curve with a line.

I was also having the same problem and I initially thought that using an `S` (or `s`) command, in the case of a Cubic Bézier Curve, would solve the problem but it didn't.

Below I'm creating the same shape three times, the only difference is the last command given to each `path` element.

The first one (with the red circle) has: `c -20 -10, -20 -30, -20 -30`

The second one (with the green circle) has: `c -20 0, -20 -30, -20 -30`

The third one (with the blue circle) has: `s -20 0, -20 -30`

**So, the key point here is to keep the first `y` coordinate unchanged when connecting a Cubic Bézier Curve with a horizontal line.**

This means for a relative command (`c` or `s`) set it to `0` and for an absolute command (`C` or `S`) set it to the `y` coordinate where the curve is joined with the line.

*Note: When connecting a Bézier Curve with a vertical line, it would be the first `x` coordinate that should be kept unchanged.*

```css
svg {
  fill: grey;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <circle id="highlightCircle" cx="70" cy="0" r="10" fill="none" stroke-width="2" />
  </defs>

  <path d="M 90 10
          c 60 0, 60 30, 60 60
          c -20 -30, -40 -30, -60 -30
          h -20 0
          c -20 -10, -20 -30, -20 -30" />
  <use href="#highlightCircle" y="40" stroke="red" />

  <path d="M 90 70
          c 60 0, 60 30, 60 60
          c -20 -30, -40 -30, -60 -30
          h -20 0
          c -20 0, -20 -30, -20 -30" />
  <use href="#highlightCircle" y="100" stroke="green" />

  <path d="M 90 130
          c 60 0, 60 30, 60 60
          c -20 -30, -40 -30, -60 -30
          h -20 0
          s -20 0, -20 -30" />
  <use href="#highlightCircle" y="160" stroke="blue" />
</svg>
```

By *"the first `y` coordinate"* I meant,

`y1` or `dy1` when using:

```
C x1 y1, x2 y2, x y
(or)
c dx1 dy1, dx2 dy2, dx dy
```

`y2` or `dy2` when using:

```
S x2 y2, x y
(or)
s dx2 dy2, dx dy
```

*P.S. I believe the same would work for a Quadratic Bézier Curve as well, I just didn't try it.*